# Cannot resolve symbol 'security' while importing io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jwt, pom.xml

I was trying to build a project about API authentication using JWT. I have installed the io.jsonwebtoken package with version 0.9.1 in order to do that.

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>jwt_api_authentication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jwt_api_authentication</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <!-- JSON Web Token Support -->
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

While I'm trying to import "io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys" I'm getting this error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'security'".

I tried 0.6.0 but still no luck.

How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have this configuration in my pom.xml. This worked for me. I removed the dependency as you have in the question and replaced it with below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**Edit: 27 Jan 2023**

Updated versions of the libs to the latest version 0.11.5 from earlier 0.11.1 in the answer.

Comment: Ah yes, my instructor said trying to use the bundle had some issues but separate jars work.

Comment: For the problem mentioned - only "jjwt-api" usage is enough!

Answer (score 5):

Based on https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys%20AND%20g:io.jsonwebtoken (this is how you can get the list of artifacts with a specific groupId containing a specific class), you need at least 0.10.0 ofjjwt-api

Comment: But why I didn't find upper than 0.10 version in the central maven repository? And How can I add this dependency in my pom.xml?

Comment: I got it. It solved my problem. Thank you very much for your time and the answer

Comment: @user3646212 After 0.10 version you need to import both api and impl dependencies.